# Can a cleric spontaneously convert a wand into a cure/inflict spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, magic-items, class-feature

As stated in an [answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/71194/23058) to a different question I had, Activating a wand (or stave) does count as casting a spell.

Spontaneous Casting

> A good cleric (or a neutral cleric of a good deity) ***can channel stored spell energy*** into healing spells that she did not prepare ahead of time. ***The cleric can “lose” any prepared spell*** that is not an orison or domain spell in order to cast any cure spell of the same spell level or lower (a cure spell is any spell with “cure” in its name).

So this comes down to channeling stored spell energy, which I think is an apt description of a scroll (or even scrolls and potions, just with different activation methods), and the lose of the prepared spell.

So could a good cleric have a wand of Air bubble (1st level spell CL1) into a spell of Cure light wounds CL1?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, wands never give you a prepared spell, so you cannot “‘lose’ any prepared spell [...] in order to cast any cure spell of the same level or lower.” When you activate the wand, you are able to cast the spell contained therein, but while this process is no doubt similar to finishing the casting of a prepared spell, it is not described in the rules as being the same thing. A scroll actually gets closer, since it says “The preparation is done for the caster, so no preparation time is needed beforehand as with normal spellcasting,” but the “prepared spell” still isn’t given to the spellcaster, it is still contained in the scroll (until you actually cast it, at which point it’s cast, not prepared at all).